# Why abstract implementation is returned by Map.values()?

Tags: java, collections

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1, "String1");
map.put(2, "String2");
map.put(3, "String3");
```

I wanted to convert the `map`'s values to set. I know I could easily do

```java
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(map.values());
```

While thinking about this, I was curious what is `map.values()` by itself anyway? So I tried this

```java
System.out.println("Set:"+ (map.values() instanceof Set));      
System.out.println("List:"+ (map.values() instanceof List));    
System.out.println("Queue:"+ (map.values() instanceof Queue));
System.out.println("SortedSet:"+ (map.values() instanceof SortedSet));
```

And the output surprisingly was

```java
Set:false
List:false
Queue:false
SortedSet:false
```

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values) is all the documentation says.

> a collection view of the values contained in this map

I then looked at the decompiled class file.

```java
public Collection<V> values() {
    if (values == null) {
        values = new AbstractCollection<V>() {
            public Iterator<V> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<V>() {
                    private Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return i.hasNext();
                    }

                    public V next() {
                        return i.next().getValue();
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        i.remove();
                    }
                };
            }

            public int size() {
                return AbstractMap.this.size();
            }

            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return AbstractMap.this.isEmpty();
            }

            public void clear() {
                AbstractMap.this.clear();
            }

            public boolean contains(Object v) {
                return AbstractMap.this.containsValue(v);
            }
        };
    }
    return values;
}
```

Why does java return an abstract implementation instead of `List`/`Set`/`Queue` which could be immediately compatible with use cases?

Comment: This way the internal representation is made accessible without having to copy the Map/Set to a new collection or having to make you dependent on implementation details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which Java version you are using, but I don't see an abstract class instance returned by `values()`. It returns an instance of `TreeMap.Values`, which is a class that extends `AbstractCollection`.

As to why it doesn't return a `Set` - that's simply due to the fact that the collection of values may contain duplicates, which a `Set` doesn't allow.

A `List` is also not ideal, since it would imply the values are ordered, which is not true for all `Map` implementations (such as `HashMap`).

BTW, instead of printing things like `map.values() instanceof Set`, you could have simply printed `map.value().getClass().getName()` to see the actual implementation class.

Comment: This is from `java8`.

Answer (score 3):

One reasons just from looking at the implementation: `contains` and `iterator` both look at the current contents of the map as opposed to the contents of the map when `values()` was called.

If you call `values()` and then change something in the map that change will be reflected in the `Collection` originally returned from `values()`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("some", "thing");
Collection<String> values = map.values();
System.out.println(values.size()); // 1
map.put("foo", "bar");
System.out.println(values.size()); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashset internally uses HashMap hence there is not much copy of values occured in the scenario.

You can see related link to get more about it. [Reference Link](https://codepumpkin.com/hashset-internal-implementation/).

where has coming to abstract collection, Below are some of Related information fetched from Java Doc:

1] This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection
  interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.

2]  To implement an unmodifiable collection, the programmer needs only to
  extend this class and provide implementations for the `<tt>iterator</tt>` and
  `<tt>size</tt>` methods.  (The iterator returned by the `<tt>iterator</tt>`
  method must implement `<tt>hasNext</tt>` and `<tt>next</tt>`.

3]  To implement a modifiable collection, the programmer must additionally
  override this `class's <tt>add</tt>` method (which otherwise throws an
  `UnsupportedOperationException`), and the iterator returned by the
  iterator method must additionally implement its `remove`
  method.

Hope this was helpful.